# Restoring Android apps and settings on new redmi 4 from backup not possible

Tags: xiaomi, google-backup

I used to use a Samsung Galaxy S5 and now switched to a Xiaomi Redmi 4.  I have backup'd my phone settings and app settings to my google account.  However, when I initialize my new phone, there is no such option as to whether I want to restore from a backup. My google drive says it has backup settings for 16 apps.  Also in the new phone, when browsing in the google drive app, there's no option to restore any kind of settings.

How do I get my apps and settings (especially wifi passwords) back?

Answer (score 0):

- The Restore backup option is only present while setting up the phone first time.
- So, You will have to factory reset your new phone and choose option to restore settings from other phone.
- You will see a page to restore your data from a previous backup while setting up the device named "Which Device" or something similar.
  [image]
- Choose your Samsung Galaxy S5 from the list.

Comment: Hi Shailesh, thanks for the detailed walkthrough. That's exactly the page I had expected, but which I did not get. There was nothing to choose from, neither on the first nor on the second attempt. Any idea why this might be? I read there is no downward compatibility...

Comment: @MERose I had the same problem while setting up my new Mi 9T. I had finally able to restore data when I specified Wi-Fi password during the initial setup process.